# Android WebView - see page in full size (like on pc)

Tags: android, webview

I think that title say all important, I want it to http://studiodamage.sweb.cz/.

My code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, container, false);
    WebView webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20 Safari/537.31");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://studiodamage.sweb.cz/");
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant to view website as a *desktop site*  try:

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

OR

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgent(1);//for desktop 1 or mobil 0.
```

OR

Try something more desktop browser looking such as:

```
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
```

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal: Its not working webview.getSettings().setUserAgent(1);//for desktop 1 or mobil 0.

Comment: Which version u were used

Comment: @koca2000 : Can you please tell me in which version (android studio) its working. Because the same code is not working in android studio latest version 3.0.1

Comment: I would like to know whether its a version upgraded issue or some other issues.

Comment: @ASV It would be API version problem rather than android studio. I was developing in eclipse when I asked this question.

Comment: Okay, Actually the same problem am facing in android studio webview so that I asked .

Comment: This is my issue please check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946658/android-webview-desktop-website-wont-work/47958325#47958325

Answer (score 0):

```
 webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("1"); //for desktop 1 or mobile 0.
```

Now this is in 12/2021

Comment: not working at all.