# Webview Desktop website won't work in Android

Tags: android, webview, webclient, whatsapp, google-chrome-webview

Partly as an exercise for learning a little Android programming, and partly because I wish I had a WhatsApp client on Android mobile, I am trying to create an app that I can personally use as a WhatsApp client for my mobile. All it does is load up the web.whatsapp.com desktop site in a UIWebView like so:

```
webView =  findViewById(R.id.wv);
String ua = "user agent string";
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(" url ");

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
        webView.clearHistory();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
});
```

This works okay. It does in fact load the correct web app first time alone, if the activity load the web view rather than redirecting to the original page as would usually happen when the server detects a mobile device. However, rather than presenting actual page its redirect me to another page,

Now, if I use WhatsApp Web from chrome on my mobile (and requesting Desktop version), it works perfectly fine, I am requesting the Desktop site for my UIWebView by setting the UserAgent. Now, I am wondering why it would not work in the WebView, and whether perhaps there is some other header or value that needs to be set in order to convince the App to work within my WebView or manifest.

I am unfamiliar with Android development. I have searched the web for an answer to this question but I could not find one.

Comment: try putting loadUrl() after setting the WebViewClient

Comment: @rainmaker Thanks for your response . I tried it same result

Comment: In fact the above solution working good in android emulator.

Comment: I searched a lot but couldn't figure out the solution. Could you please any one help me.

Comment: @Rainmaker Could you suggest me any other solutions.

Comment: i tried https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView and crosswalk nothing helped me

Comment: I've never faced such a problem, don't have other ideas , sorry

Comment: It’s okay thank you

Comment: Its horrible still i didn't figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The site likely uses Bootstrap and just proportions the screen based on display size.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but am not familiar with bootstrap, Can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: If i do clear cache it would work, second time onwards it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

can you please change 
String ua="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101Firefox/4.0";
and try out.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, This works okay. It does in fact load the correct webapp, rather than redirecting to the whatsapp home page as would usually open ask me to select the browser page